# WPF load many items to Grid and display on new available row/column

Tags: wpf, grid

I created a grid on my WPF application with 4 rows and columns to display media:

```
        <Grid Name="ControlsGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
```

And from another method i add to the grid:

```
            WindowsFormsHost formhost = new WindowsFormsHost();
            formhost.Child = new System.Windows.Forms.Control();
            formhost.Child = control;
            ControlsGrid.Children.Add(formhost);
```

The objects are loading fine, during debug i see the size of collection increases.. but the control is being displayed on the first 0,0 grid and when adding a new control it over ride the control that was there.
How can i set the control on an empty place on the grid ?

Comment: So you want to add a new WinformsHost to each Grid Column/Row? Also is `VideosGrid` a different `Grid` than `ControlsGrid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` for the controls to be in each space.

However I noticed you are setting all the Grid Columns/Rows the same size, so perhaps UniformGrid would be a better option

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication16.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">
    <UniformGrid Name="ControlsGrid" Rows="4" Columns="4" />
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddWinformControls();
    }

    private void AddWinformControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            WindowsFormsHost formhost = new WindowsFormsHost();
            formhost.Child = new System.Windows.Forms.Label() { Text = "Hello" };
            ControlsGrid.Children.Add(formhost);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also, Do you know if WindowsFormsHost is good for only 1 control or should i add all controls to its child.controls ?

Comment: I have never used WindowsFormsHost, so I'm not sure sorry

Answer (score 1):

You will need a way to determine the next empty space and then you need to set the grid row and column attached properties:

```
        Grid.SetRow(control, row);
        Grid.SetColumn(control, column);
```